# What is the best way to handle i18n in an Angular app with dynamic translations

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internationalization, typescript

So I have been tasked with i18n on a new Angular app we are creating. I already know how to implement it if the translations are stored in json format on the client. However I have been told I cannot implement it like this as the translations will get updated on a regular basis by the client so must will have to be got from the api.

I have also been told that I cannot map directly to the json response, but instead I must create TypeScript objects which sit between the json and the UI.

What is the best way to achieve this? The header has a dropdown for languages. Do I need to call all the languages when the application loads and cache them, or do I just call each language as I need to? Do I translate only what I see on screen or does the entire app need to be translated?

Answer (score 0):

> do I just call each language as I need to

Definitely only the ones you need.

> Do I translate only what I see on screen or does the entire app need to be translated

The relevant portions get redirected to an in memory `i18n` angular service that has the results cached.